# How to start docker container after succesfull wait-for-it script

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash, docker

I'm using a wait-for-it script to check if the database is up before I'm launching my other app.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

I found this script [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).
Now my app-container stops running with `MySQL is up - executing command`.
So the script was successful (db is running) but it's not clear for me how to execute the real CMD (after the script) which is in my dockerfile of my app.

This is the end of my dockerfile:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 2368
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: You can remove `ENTRYPOINT` and put both in `CMD`: `CMD /entrypoint.sh && npm start`.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but it seems still unable to execute the command on CMD after the succesful psql check. So the image is build, my docker-compose executes the wait-for-it script, it's succesful so my container can start but there it goes wrong. Nothing happens

Comment: I think the wait-for-it script needs arguments. Try `/entrypoint.sh localhost npm start`. Sorry I cannot test right now as I don't have a Linux box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clear up a couple of things first. When you use both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in a Dockerfile, the `CMD` value is passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as a parameter. So what you currently have in the file translates to

```
/entrypoint.sh npm start
```

This is executed when you start the container. Without knowing what's happening in `entrypoint.sh`, it's hard to tell what impact this has.

## Docker

You could make the following changes, please give this a try:

- Remove the `ENTRYPOINT` from the `Dockerfile`.
- Change `CMD` to the following:

  ```
  CMD /wait-for-it.sh localhost && /entrypoint.sh npm start
  ```

When doing that, please adjust the following:

- The path for `wait-for-it.sh` - please adjust to wherever you're copying the script file in the Dockerfile. I suggest you copy it to the same folder as `entrypoint.sh`.
- The `localhost` argument for the `wait-for-it.sh` script file, please replace with your database host.

What the above does, is run the `wait-for-it.sh` script and then, once the database is up, it runs the previous command that you had in `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. It should be comparable to what you currently have.

As an alternative, you could also call the `wait-for-it.sh` script from your `entrypoint.sh` script and only run the additional steps (`npm start` once the wait script has succeeded). Up to you...

## Docker-Compose

If you are using Docker-Compose for starting up your containers, you can overwrite the command that is executed when the container starts using the `command` attribute in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, e.g.

```
command: >
  bash -c "

  /wait-for-it.sh localhost 
  && /entrypoint.sh npm start
  "
```

Please note the use of

- `bash -c` for starting multiple commands using your shell of choice (Bash in this case)
- the quotes, you'll need them for having multiple lines.

Using this method, you can basically chain multiple commands to run after each other, combining them using the `&&` operator.

## Wait-for-it Script

BTW: I use this [wait-for-it script](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) for a similar purpose with good results in the same manner as described above. It's slightly more robust than you version of the wait script, and supports pretty much any host/port combination. I use it to wait for MySQL - your question is not clear whether it's about MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm using mysql but the script is copied from the docker documentation but adapted for mysql and working good. I also try to start it with docker-compose so do I still need to edit the dockerfile?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a section about Docker-Compose